# What is wrong with this jquery code, its driving my crazy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an id `textarea_feedback` and a textarea with an id `msg`.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text_max = 160;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');
    $('#msg').keyup(function(){
        var text_length = $('#msg').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
        $('#textarea_feeeback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you also post your related html code?

Comment: what exactly isnt working? errors? not doing what you want it to do? ..what do you want it to do?

Comment: textarea_feedback vs textarea_feeeback ,thats not jquery fualt

Comment: check feedback spelling

Comment: @PatrickEvans There wouldn't have been any errors...why do you say that?

Comment: @Ian yea just remembered jquery doesnt throw an error for that (accessing a function of null error) like if you did it with plain js.

Comment: @Dexture Silent failure, however, *is* jQuery's fault.

Answer (score 4):

`$('#textarea_feeeback')` is a typo.

This is actually a very concrete example of the power of [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) over jQuery, and of jQuery being too clever for its own good. The Vanilla JS code:

```
document.getElementById('textarea_feeeback').innerHTML = text_remaining+" characters remaining";
```

... would have thrown an error saying that it can't set `innerHTML` of null, which is absolutely correct because `textarea_feeeback` does not exist. jQuery, however, simply has an object with no elements, and setting the `html()` of those zero elements is really easy: do nothing.

Unfortunately, "do nothing" is the reason why you can't debug it!

Comment: I'm pretty sure answers shouldn't be provided for questions that have a typo...there's an option to close the question for exactly that.

Comment: @ian: then don't up/down vote answers. let the question get closed as a typo, and the OP gets the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#textarea_feeeback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
                    ^--- typo
```